# Where did Morra go for a holiday?

Tags: film-location, limitless

In this movie Limitless, Morra was invited by a group of friends to a tropical country where he drives a Maserati and jumps off a cliff.

[image]

[image]

Where did he visit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Puerto Vallarta, Mexico

> (To be exact, at the junction of Morelos  and Paseo Diaz Ordez, right on along the waterfront Malecon area – in front of Senor Frog’s bar, where a lot of the “Girls Gone Wild” videos come from.)
>
> The bigger question is why was that filmed there, of all places? That’s where the filmmakers wanted to go, it seems. According to locals, the crew was in town for almost six weeks, starting in June 2010 for the filming. Doesn’t it seem like six weeks is a long time to be “on location” for less than 30 seconds of footage? Yes, it does! (Possible motivation: See the Senor Frog’s explanation above.)
>
> So this brings up a lot of other questions. Such as how did the Maserati get to Puerto Vallarta? According to the [**Hollywood Reporter**](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/how-maserati-landed-spots-limitless-166655), there were two identical cars; one from Maserati’s Mexico distributor, and another that was shipped in from the U.S. Maserati apparently paid nothing for this delectable bit of product placement. From what I know of Puerto Vallarta, a Maserati is a rare sight indeed.

<sup>[**Source**](https://jerrygarrett.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/ten-secrets-behind-how-limitless-was-filmed/)</sup>